# ios animation. How nested animations affect duration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

Let's say I have a timed UIAnimation, in the format of

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION_X
                 animations:^
 {
     [function that might contain a separate animation with DURATION_Y]
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [function that might contain a separate animation with DURATION_Z]
 }];
```

If the nested animations also have durations inside them, how does that affect the outer animation?  Are the inner animations executed with DURATION_Y and DURATION_Z, respectively, no matter what DURATION_X happens to be?  Or is DURATION_Y animations scaled down or curtailed to end with respect to DURATION_X, assuming DURATION_X <= DURATION_Y?

Basically, what I'm asking in a nutshell is how we can control duration of inner animations safely, to ensure they execute with DURATION_Y (and not some shorter version) even when the outermost animation has a different and shorter DURATION_X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU, the inner animation takes control over the duration which is mentioned in the outer animation block. Whereas, function inside the completion block does not seem to wait until the  main animation block finishes its animation task with the given time duration.

So, lets say DURATION_X is 5 seconds, DURATION_Y is 20 seconds and DURATION_Z is 10 seconds respectively. What happens is that the animation function inside the completion block gets triggered once the control completes (going to the function and do whatever) the main animation block (Having said the function inside the main animation block does have a different time duration). Hence, the function inside the completion block gets executed with the DURATION_Z and it does animate for the exact duration mentioned in DURATION_Z.

Along the side, the function inside the main animation block gets executed for the time duration specified in the DURATION_X ONLY. It ignores the time duration of DURATION_Y. A wacky code snippet here is:

```
-(void)doSomeAnim
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                     animations:^
     {
         [self animateOrangeBoy];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [self animateBlueBoy];
     }];

}

-(void)animateOrangeBoy
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:20.0 animations:^{
        orangeView.frame = CGRectMake(orangeView.frame.origin.x, orangeView.frame.origin.y + 300, orangeView.frame.size.width, orangeView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}

-(void)animateBlueBoy
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 animations:^{
        blueView.frame = CGRectMake(blueView.frame.origin.x, blueView.frame.origin.y + 300, blueView.frame.size.width, blueView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

So, `animateBlueBoy` also starts along with the `animateOrangeBoy` but `animateOrangeBoy` lasts only 5 seconds but `animateBlueBoy` goes till 10 seconds.

Comment: Good example!  Question: Why doesn't animateBlueBoy start AFTER five seconds?  Isn't the completion block meant to start after the original animation (DURATION_X) finishes?  One more question: In regards to DURATION_Y, does animateOrangeBoy just get cut-off uncleanly mid-animation?  Or is the animation scaled to fit into 5.0 seconds?  (i.e. DURATION_Y is auto-set without us knowing to 5.0, so it finishes cleanly in DURATION_X)

Comment: 1. DURATION_X meant to be the time that it takes to animate whatever inside the main block. You only call a method inside that. The completion block (animateOrangeBoy who has DURATION_Y) gets called as soon as the main block finishes calling the method. Hence, OrangeBoy gets triggered (Note that DURATION_X animation still runs).

Comment: 2. I ran the code with a timer and did notice that the animation runs only 5 seconds (regardless we set it to run for 20 seconds inside the orangeBoy method). So, it looks to me as it automatically scales itself to 5 seconds (PS: I set the DURATION_Y to 100 seconds as well as 1 second, both seem to have run only 5 seconds which is set in the outer block or main block)

Comment: (1) Wait, now I am confused.  The completion block in your code is animateBlueBoy, NOT animateOrangeBoy.  So I am wondering why animateBlueBoy runs immediately, rather than waiting for completion.

Comment: (2) Thank you for testing this. I know how much it runs, I am wondering if it is run cleanly.  "cleanly" means the animation completes smoothly, without a sudden end. For example, if animateOrangeBoy (inside the animations block, NOT the completion block) is an animation with frames 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., DURATION_Y, then do you see 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., DURATION_X (< DURATION_Y), or do you see all frames 1, 2, 3, ..., DURATION_Y, except they happen faster with less than a second in between?  I.e. is the default behavior to truncate to DURATION_X, or interpolate/scale to DURATION_X?

Comment: (1). Oops.. I am sorry. Yes, the completion block holds animateBlueBoy.. The reason is that the 5.0 seconds is the allocated time duration for whatever inside main block. It's just 'animateWithduration' not 'delay'. So, it doesn't delay the animation until main block gets executed. Main block only has a method to be executed. So, as soon as the main block completes its task, the control comes to the completion block and executes animateBlueBoy.. So, the key here is difference between "animateWithDuration" and "delay"

Comment: (2). It was quite smooth and didn't have any rough end

Comment: Thank you for pointing out animate... delay. That is the key difference.